# Connecting cross referenced nets to inout ports in verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I am prototyping an ASIC on Xilinx FPGA, which has a third party DDR interface. In order to implement the design, the ASIC DDR controller is replaced with a Xilinx DDR4 controller. This controller sits deep in the module hierarchy and I am trying to connect the controller interface to FPGA IO pins using cross referencing. This looks like below.

```
assign DDR_ADR = dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_adr;
assign DDR_CKE = dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_cke;
...
alias DDR_DQ = dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_dq; // inout port
alias DDR_DQS_T = dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_dqs_t; // inout port
alias DDR_DQS_C = dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_dqs_c; // inout port
```

where `DDR_*` are FPGA IO ports declared as wires.

I am using Synopsys' protocompiler tool chain to synthesise the design. I learned that the tool doesn't support aliases on cross references. The assign statements on cross references work fine though.

Is there an alternative approach to connect these cross referenced nets to `inout` ports? I am not allowed to modify the ASIC RTL to bring the controller nets to the top module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the suggestions related to explicit port declaration and I think Synopsys doesn't support that. For @dave_59 suggestion I get "Feature is not yet supported: Port declaration specification is not yet implemented".

But taking inspiration from @TomCarpenter's answer I wrote the module as,

```
module bidir_via #(
  parameter W = 1 
) (
  inout [W-1:0] a,
  inout [W-1:0] b
);

alias a = b;

endmodule
```

Then at the top level I used,

```
bidir_via #(.W(64)) DDR_DQ_via (.a(DDR_DQ), .b(dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_dq));
```

This logic compiled into INOUT ports and I was able to read/write the DDR4 memory in Hardware. Apparently, Synopsys doesn't support aliases on cross module references, but for normal nets aliases work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a port aliasing "via" module, which is a common technique to join bidirectional buses in Verilog. I have no idea if this will work with Synopsys and cross references, but worth a go.

For example in your top level you could have something like (where `W` is the signal width):

```
bidir_via #(.W(4)) DDR_DQ_via (.a(DDR_DQ), .b(dut.ddr_inst.behav.ctrl.c0_ddr4_dq));
```

With the via module being defined as:

```
module bidir_via #(
    parameter W = 1
) (.a(w), .b(w)); 
inout [W-1:0] w;
endmodule
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. Synopsys VCS marked the module as a black box as it finds it empty, and Vivado P&R fails as a result. It is an interesting idea though, thanks, will be useful in the future. 
And this is the first time I am seeing a module defined like that. I don't fully understand it, but I assume `a` and `b` are named ports that connect to `w` internally? Why is `w` declared twice - as inout port and wire?

Comment: @matryx Come to think of it, I have a feeling that the extra `wire w` declaration is unnecessary, just a bad copy paste error - I've ended up copying that construct so many times. It's called `Explicit Port Declaration` where basically the port names exposed map to a different internal port name. So there is one port called `w` internally, then externally we have ports `a` and `b` that both connect to the internal `w` port.

Comment: If it's getting upset because it's an empty module, you could always try adding some other trivial logic into it and see if that helps. Other normal ports can be added along with the weird aliased ones.

Comment: @matryx see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333159/2755607) to get more information about this port syntax

Comment: I tried the suggestions related to explicit port declaration and I think Synopsys doesn't support that. For @dave_59 suggestion I get "Feature is not yet supported: Port declaration specification is not yet implemented". But taking inspiration from @TomCarpenter's answer I wrote the module as `module bidir_via #( parameter W = 1 ) ( inout [W-1:0] a, inout [W-1:0] b ); alias a = b; endmodule`. Apparently, Synopsys doesn't support aliases on cross module references but for normal nets, it works. This compiled into INOUT ports and I was able to read/write to the DDR4 memory in Hardware.

Comment: @matryx Glad you sorted it. Feel free to post that as an answer